# Angular changes aren't being saved to the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function `approveArticle(art)` called from a view in the following way:

```
<td>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success disabled" ng-show="art.approved">Approved</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="article.approveArticle(art)" ng-show="!art.approved">Approve</a>
</td>
```

(here `article` is the controller and `art` comes from the following ng-repeat: `<tr ng-repeat="art in article.articles">`

The function in the controller looks like the following:

```
vm.approveArticle = function (art) {
    art.approved = true;
};
```

The view changes as expected, after clicking, the "Approve" button is being replaced with the disabled "Approved" button. However, the changes aren't being saved to the database (I've been checking with Robomongo - also, upon refresh, the approvals are gone).

How can I save these changes to the model? Help appreciated.

`ArticleSchema`:

```
var ArticleSchema   = new Schema({
    title: { type: String },
    author: { type: String },
    body: { type: String },
    comments: [{
        body: { type: String },
        date: { type: Date }
    }],
    approved: { type: Boolean },
    created_at: { type: Date },
    updated_at: { type: Date }
});
```

`GET` and `PUT` routes for Article:

```
articleRouter.route('/articles/:article_id')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        Article.findById(req.params.article_id, function (err, article) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(article);
        });
    })
    .put(function (req, res) {
        Article.findById(req.params.article_id, function (err, article) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            if (req.body.title) {
                article.title   = req.body.title;
            }
            if (req.body.author) {
                article.author  = req.body.author;
            }
            if (req.body.body) {
                article.body    = req.body.body;
            }
            if (req.body.date) {
                article.date    = req.body.date;
            }
            if (req.body.hidden) {
                article.hidden  = req.body.hidden;
            }
            article.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.json({ message: 'Article updated!' });
            });
        });
    });
```

`articleController`:

```
    .controller('articleController', function (Article) {
    'use strict';
    var vm = this;
    vm.processing = true;
    Article.all()
        .success(function (data) {
            vm.processing = false;
            vm.articles = data;
        });
    vm.deleteArticle = function (id) {
        if (confirm("You are about to delete an article!")) {
            vm.processing = true;
            Article['delete'](id)
                .success(function (data) {
                    Article.all()
                        .success(function (data) {
                            vm.processing = false;
                            vm.articles = data;
                        });
                });
        }
    };
    vm.approveArticle = function (art) {
        art.approved = true;
    };
});
```

`articleEditController`:
(I have a sensation that this might be highly relevant)

```
.controller('articleEditController', function ($routeParams, Article) {
    'use strict';
    var vm = this;
    vm.type = 'edit';
    Article.get($routeParams.article_id)
        .success(function (data) {
            vm.articleData = data;
        });
    vm.saveArticle = function () {
        vm.processing = true;
        vm.message = '';
        Article.update($routeParams.article_id, vm.articleData)
            .success(function (data) {
                vm.processing = false;
                vm.articleData = {};
                vm.message = data.message;
            });
    };
});
```

`articleService.js`, containing the relevant factories:

```
angular
    .module('articleService', [])
    .factory('Article', function ($http) {
        'use strict';

        var articleFactory = {};

        articleFactory.get = function (id) {
            return $http.get('/api/article/articles/' + id);
        };

        articleFactory.all = function () {
            return $http.get('/api/article/articles/');
        };

        articleFactory.create = function (articleData) {
            return $http.post('/api/article/articles/', articleData);
        };

        articleFactory.update = function (id, articleData) {
            return $http.put('/api/article/articles/' + id, articleData);
        };

        articleFactory['delete'] = function (id) {
            return $http['delete']('/api/article/articles/' + id);
        };

        return articleFactory;
    });
```

Comment: You need to have some code that actually posts or otherwise sends the data to the server. Do you do that anywhere?

Comment: @SunilD. I don't. I tried a few ideas, but all of them triggered an error in the terminal. I think the `approveArticle` function shouldn't end with the assignment, but I don't know how I could save it.

Comment: @SunilD. what I tried most is sort of replicating the update function that I use for my edit view, but that didn't do it.

Comment: Can you please only post the "appropriate" code to the problem you are experiencing and also "post" that code within your question rather  than use external links that can dissappear over time. Would love to help you but you are not exactly making it easy for people to help. Explain your actual problem clearly please.

Comment: What BlakesSeven says is really helpful, it's difficult to piece things together when they are in 4 separate URLs. I know it's hard to figure out what might be relevant... In this case your controller and article service are relevant. Inside the `approveArticle()` function you should probably call the article service to save the article:  `Article.update(art.id, art)` ... or something like that.

Comment: @SunilD. tried `Article.update(art.id, art);` before, it yields an error: `Cannot set property title of undefined`

Comment: @SunilD. "See what I did there?" that's called "tagging" so I actually see your remark and don't need to go look for it. My comments are about submitting the question in an appriate format for SO, which means complete and self contained and to the point. Can you please limit your own "critique" to the author and most importantly submit a response if you think you have an answer please.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Perhaps you missed the snarky reply from the OP to you (which seems to have been deleted now). I was suggesting to the OP that his snarky reply wasn't necessary. Now everyone's got snarky replies :)

Comment: @BlakesSeven I think I've made the required changes. Can you help now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I was only changing the property on the client side, without changing anything on the server. What I've come up with is the following.

I added an `approve` method to the `Article` model, as following:

```
ArticleSchema.methods.approve = function (cb) {
    'use strict';
    this.approved = true;
    this.save(cb);
};
```

Then, I created an API route for approving the article:

```
articleRouter.route('/articles/:article_id/approve')
    .put(function (req, res) {
        Article.findById(req.params.article_id, function (err, article) {
            article.approve(function (err, article) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.json({ message: 'Article approved' });
            });
        });
    });
```

Then, I created a basic call in my factory, so that I can reuse the code:

```
articleFactory.approve = function (id) {
    return $http.put('/api/article/articles/' + id + '/approve');
};
```

Finally, I rewrote the function in the controller, as follows:

```
vm.approveArticle = function (art) {
    if (confirm("You are about to approve an article!")) {
        Article.approve(art._id)
            .success(function (data) {
                flash.success = 'Article approved!';
                art.approved = true;
            });
    }
};
```

Here, I'm calling the approve method so that a `PUT` call is sent to the API. Upon success, I'm both launching a flash message (using `angular-flash`) and changing the state of the current object so that the view instantly reflects the changes.

I'm not sure about the last part (maybe there is a nicer way than `art.approved = true;`), but this works as I intended.